# Bokeh bar plot: how to supress aggregation name at y-axis label?

Tags: python, bokeh

Consider bar plots in bokeh (python)
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/user_guide/charts.html

On the Y-axis, we always see label like "SUM(NAME)", here "SUM" is name of aggregation function (can be mean ...).

**Question** Is there any way to suppress it ? Just to see "NAME" ?

Example:

```
data = {
    'L': ['A','B', 'C'],
    'NAME': [100, 2, 200]
}

bar = Bar(data, values='NAME',  plot_height=400,  label=['L'], legend = None, title="someTitle", plot_width=400)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update to Bokeh 0.12.* you can do this:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file('bar_colors.html')

data = {
    'L': ['A','B', 'C'],
    'NAME': [100, 2, 200],
}

p = figure(x_range=data['L'], y_range=(0,300), plot_height=400, plot_width=400,
           title='someTitle', toolbar_location=None, tools='')

p.vbar(x='L', top='NAME', width=0.9, legend=None, source=data)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'NAME'

show(p)
```

Result:

[image: Plot]

Comment: thank you very much ! So seems no way to do it with "bar", should only use "vbar" ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Seems that `bokeh.charts` has been dropped altogether in 0.12.*, but looking again at the documentation seems that you can change the axes labels in those too, I updated the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Apparently ultimately removed in 0.12.9, see [release notes](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#deprecated-bokeh-charts-support-removed). Seems it was a deprecated interface to [bkcharts](https://github.com/bokeh/bkcharts), which itself seems to have been deprecated in favor of [HoloViews](https://holoviews.org/).

Comment: Just to add some context, `bkcharts` has alwasy been deprecated/unsupported. It was all the `bokeh.charts` code (including `Bar`) that got removed. Since then, `vbar` and `vbar_stack` and more have been added to the stable `bokeh.plotting` API, and those are now better and more featureful than the old `bokeh.charts` ever was. HoloViews is a separate project that builds on top of Bokeh. It's entirely optional, but many people like its concise, high level, data-centric API, especially for exploratory work.

Comment: @jdehesa FYI it's now possible to pass `data` dicts directly as the `source` arg. If you don't to share a `ColumnDataSource`, then that makes the code a little shorter. I've updated your example.